# Mono WinForms and Unicode characters

Tags: unicode, mono, monodevelop

I am working on a VS2010 C# application that allows users to input data in *English as well as in Hindi (Unicode).

The application is working well in Windows, but in Linux (with Mono-2.10.8), instead of displaying Unicode characters it show boxes.

[mono unicode problem http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1395/vry.png](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1395/vry.png)

I have tried to run it on Debian Wheezy Stable and Ubuntu LTS 12.04. I have also tried to compile it with MonoDevelop; still no luck.

Is there any workaround to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution that i want to share with the community.

The problem was with local. I set environment var LANG to hi_IN.utf-8 and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Boxes like this is usually a sign that the codepoints displayed are not present in the font currently used. Did you make sure you were using a font with Hindi characters?

Comment: Hindi unicode support is already available as i am able to see Hindi characters in browser. It is not working in **mono Winforms controls**. It is problem not just with Hindi, it is with any unicode character.

Comment: @SamTech ["A" is a Unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0041/). Are you saying the problem exists with "A" as well?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue with Japanese. I fixed my issue by changing `LANG=ja_JP.utf-8`.