# Mono fails rendering Chinese text in WindowsForms Textbox

Tags: winforms, fonts, mono, cjk, text-rendering

I  need some Chinese in a form, but running in Linux with Mono it fails. Any tips?
Example:

```
// works OK in windows and Linux same text.
Console.WriteLine( "Test  中国 的" );

// works OK in windows fails in Linux (renders "Test  [][][][]")
MessageBox.Show("Test  中国 的");

// works OK in windows fails in Linux (renders "Test  [][][][]")
Textbox1.Text="Test  中国 的"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391758/mono-winforms-and-unicode-characters You should be able to follow the answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that you have a font set that contains Chinese characters. Then try setting environment var `LANG` to `zh_CN.utf-8` and see if that solves the problem.